# Help identify terminology for pattern substituion?

Tags: terminology

This is a badly titled question...maybe a moderator can make it better.

Nearly two decades ago, I took a computer graphics class as an undergraduate.  We got to do whatever we wanted for a final project as long as it demonstrated what we learned about CG.

So, I read a book (I can't think of the name at all) that described a methodology to generate fractal images starting with a simple shape and mutating it using substitution.  It described abstract fractals and tree/flower fractals. I do recall implementing the [Sierpinski Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) in one of my sample imputs as well as a 3D tree.

The input to the program was basically a series of arbitrary symbols defined by the program.  `-----=` might represent a rose.  Then you apply some substitutions for a given pattern.  `--= > -+=---=` might represent a longer rose with thorns.  So, applying that pattern to the initial string you get `----+=---=`. Finally you loop over this string `N` number of times to create some desired effect.

The book itself offered a ton of inputs with sample pictures, but no actual source code.  The implementation was completely left up to the developer.

I would like to know if somebody can help me with the terminology for this technique and bonus points for the name of the book (or a book) that described this process?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [term rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that you're thinking of L-systems: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenmayer_system

I found this example at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake , linked from the Sierpinski page:

```
The Koch Curve can be expressed by a rewrite system (Lindenmayer system).

Alphabet : F
Constants : +, −
Axiom : F++F++F
Production rules:
F → F−F++F−F

Here, F means "draw forward", + means "turn right 60°", and − means "turn left 60°".
```

Comment: That's it exactly!  +1000 if I could!

Comment: Here's a link to the book that I used:  http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop

Answer (score 1):

What the program is most likely doing is taking the input pattern and interpreting each symbol as a "command", which are run in a looping sequence as modifications to a basic drawing pattern. For instance, "-" might be "draw the next line segment normally". "=" might be "draw this line segment thicker than normal", ">" might be "turn left" and "<" would be "turn right", and finally "+" could mean "start drawing in three directions in parallel".

So, it's basically just a command parsing algorithm. A relatively novel one, but on the whole no more complex than something written to parse more verbose commands.